# MYSQL select count of multiple ids occurring in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I've searched for an answer to this question quite a bit, but I haven't yet found exactly how to do this.

The three relevant tables in my database are tool, purpose, and user_tools. Tool and purpose both have id and description columns, while user_tools has the columns
user_id, tool_id, and purpose_id. Tool and purpose are essentially static lookup tables, and user_tools has a row for every purpose for which a given user has used a tool.

I need to build a SELECT statement whose columns are the tool description and counts of uses for each of the different purposes listed in the purpose table. Eg. result row:

```
description | Purpose: Class | Purpose: Student Club | Purpose: Personal Project | ...

'Lathe'     |  100           |   50                  |     11                    | ...
```

I'd like to do this without having to hard code purpose_id's into the SELECT so that if I want to add new entries to the purpose table, I don't need to change my code.

The following statement gets the info I want, but it creates a new row for each different purpose count and I'd like to have them all in columns.

```
SELECT 
  tool.description, 
  count(purpose.id), 
  purpose.description 
FROM 
  user_tools LEFT OUTER JOIN tool 
ON 
  user_tools.tool_id = tool.id LEFT OUTER JOIN purpose 
ON 
  user_tools.purpose_id = purpose.id 
GROUP BY 
  tool.description, 
  purpose.description
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of writing a procedure that uses dynamic SQL, you'll have to hard-code for purpose ID's because you can't have a varying number of result columns in a query.

What you need is a PIVOT operation. Here's how it's done in MySQL:

```
SELECT
  tool.description,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN purpose.id = <ID for Class> THEN 1 END) AS `Purpose: Class`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN purpose.id = <ID for Student Club> THEN 1 END) AS `Purpose: Student Club`,
  . . . and the rest of the purpose.id values
FROM user_tools
LEFT JOIN tool ON user_tools.tool_id = tool.id
LEFT JOIN purpose ON user_tools.purpose_id = purpose_id
GROUP BY tool.description
```

Note that this answer is based on your sample query rather than any knowledge of your data. If the answer doesn't get the results you need, please post sample data and I should be able to revise the query to get your desired results.

Comment: This answer works like a charm. Since I'm using Python to interface to the DB though, I simply decided to dynamically build the SELECT statement in the Python code after selecting the contents of the purpose table.